# I'm trying to understand why I'm receiving "String seems to be unrelated to String[]"

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

Im creating a project where the area or volume of certain shapes are calculated using dropdown menus in java. I don't have any errors when compiling however I'm getting the message that "Unlikely argument type for equals(): String seems to be unrelated to String[]". As stated, it complies fine, but when running it allows area/volume to be selected, but it does not reach the next option pane to select the shapes.

The message appears on: if (choices.equals("Area"))
and : if (choices.equals("Volume"))

`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Shapes 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

//Dropdown menu for area and volume
        String[] choices = {"Area", "Volume"};
        String question = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What would you like to calculate?",
            "Shapes", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
            choices,
            choices[0]);
        System.out.println(question);

        if (choices.equals("Area"))
        {
//user chooses area
            String[] choices2D = {"triangle", "parallelogram", "rectangle", "trapezoid", "circle"};
            String question2D = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What shape will you choose?",
                "Shapes", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                choices2D,
                choices2D[0]);
            System.out.println(question2D);
        }
//user chooses volume
        if (choices.equals("Volume"))
        {
            String[] choices3D = {"cone", "cylinder", "rectanglular prism", "trapezoid prism", "sphere"};
            String question3D = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What figure will you choose?",
                "Shapes", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                choices3D,
                choices3D[0]);
            System.out.println(question3D);
        }
    }
}
```

`

I originally had the options linked to a switch but would keep running into errors, after changing it to an if statement it will compile but not run properly.

Comment: `choices` is an array of `String`s. It is meaningless to compare that to a single `String` -- they can never be equal.

Comment: I see. How could I be able to reference a value of the array instead of comparing a specific string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparisons are `choices.equals(…)`, but you meant to compare the selection from the dropbox, and this is stored in `question`. So the comparisons should be `question.equals(…)`.

Alternatively, try this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Shapes 
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        //Dropdown menu for area and volume
        String[] choices = {"Area", "Volume"};
        String question = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, 
            "What would you like to calculate?",
            "Shapes", 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
            null,
            choices,
            choices[0]) ;
        System.out.println(question);

        switch( question )
        {
            case "Area":
            {
                //user chooses area
                String[] choices2D = {"triangle", "parallelogram", "rectangle", "trapezoid", "circle"};
                String question2D = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                    "What shape will you choose?",
                    "Shapes", 
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                    null,
                    choices2D,
                    choices2D[0] );
                System.out.println( question2D );
                break;
            }

            case "Volume":
            {
                //user chooses volume
                String[] choices3D = {"cone", "cylinder", "rectanglular prism", "trapezoid prism", "sphere"};
                String question3D = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, 
                    "What figure will you choose?",
                    "Shapes", 
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                    null,
                    choices3D,
                    choices3D[0] );
                System.out.println( question3D );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the new `switch-case` syntax and optimise further, by using `enum`s for the various choices.

Comment: Ah thank you for the input. I had a similar setup but I was still using choices for my switch. It works as intended now!

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing the whole array with a single string. Use choices[0].equals("Area"). Now this will compare choices array with string at index 0 with Area.

Comment: Although this is correct, it is not what is intended. `choices [0]` is always `"Area"`, it will not change, no matter what you chose in the dialog …

Comment: int question =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What would you like to calculate?",
            "Shapes", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
            choices,
            choices[0]);  .... In the question variable you will get the choice selected by user and then compare it... If(question == 0) then area choice else volume

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).